# CakePHP 2.x: Alaxos ACL Plugin- configure the admin route

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am a cakephp beginner , have not much exposure to cakephp. 
I have followed installation step for Alaxos ACL plugin foe cakephp 2.0 from [-alaxos site](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/34#comments_list) .. there second step is configuring admin routing .

that i have done by adding

```
Router::connect('/admin/acl', array('plugin' => 'acl', 'controller' => 'acl', 'action' => 'admin_index', 'admin' => true));
```

to my Cake/Routing/Router.php file and configuring  app/Config/core.php: by adding following line

```
 Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

i am not sure whether this is the correct way of doing it...

On accessing the plugin http://localhost/cakeacl/admin/acl it gives error

```
 **Private Method in AclController
```

Error: AclController::admin_index() cannot be accessed directly.**

Please help me ..Thanks in advance...

Comment: Damned ! I should have seen this question before. This is my plugin after all... By the way, @gvLearner is correct, as I answered you on my own webpage.

Comment: Thanks nclO..Thanks for such wonderful plugin! u Rock!

Comment: @nlcO: last but not least..when the permission is denies i dont want to redirect to login page rather to page which says "You are not authorized to see this page".. How can i do it?

Comment: This comportment is done by the Auth component: if you try to access a protected action without being authenticated, you are redirect to the login page (default is */users/login*). If necessary, you should probably ask another question, as this is not related to the plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to put only the following in the `app/Config/core.php` and remove the Router configurations.

`Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));`

Comment: I have also done the same plugin in my project and worked with Routing prefixes in Core.php without any changes in the Router.php file..

Comment: @ gvLearner  :last but not least..when the permission is denies i dont want to redirect to login page rather to page which says "You are not authorized to see this page".. How can i do it?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this guide http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application from the official site yet?